# How to replace several overlapped characters with one in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string, something like that (I don't know in advance how much similar characters in a sequence):

```
s = '&&&&&word&&&word2&&&'
```

and would like to obtain as a result this string:

```
'&word&word2&'
```

Workaround is something like this (not effective I guess for large texts):

```
while True:
    if not '&&' in s:
        break
    s = s.replace('&&','&')
```

Comment: You probably meant `while '&&' in s: s = s.replace('&&', '&')`, I guess. But a regular expression is better suited for the job.

Comment: Yes, it is almost the same. Of course, I'd prefer more effective solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex to replace any occurence of one or more '&' (`&+`) by '&':

```
import re

s = '&&&&&word&&&word2&&&'

res = re.sub(r'&+', '&', s)

print(res)
# &word&word2&
```